# I want to find out how much time does each step of SOAP Processing takes i.e,Parsing time,invoking time etc?

Tags: soap, service, web

I know how to find out complete processing time of the SOAP Message but i want to find out the time taken to perform individual steps of SOAP Processing so that i can improve the efficiency

Answer (score 0):

You could always create DateTime and grab the time at the time of execution, it wont be perfect but you can then just subtract the times and get the final millisecond or seconds value from each execution.